# Recognition Property or Dynamic Object Map in RFT

Tags: rft

Currently I'm using trial version of RFT for PowerBuilder v12.5 application. During recording when we save one windows information it generate a string (unique auto generated) for variable and use it for reference to store all other information from other windows and tabs . Currently RFT use this in Object Map for reference and when we playback the script, it fails as value of the variable changes from recorded value. I am unable to change recognition properties so that during playback it does not match above variable ‘Business Partner ID’.

I need to know how I can change the recognition property so that during playblack RFT skip the matching of this value or how can I make this dynamic so that whenever during playback RFT save the information it get the unique value each time.

Your prompt response will really help me a lot, thank you in advance. In case any other details required, do let me know.

Regards,
Atif Abbas

Answer (score 0):

In cases where recognition properties of an object are dynamic , there are two approaches two handle them:

- Convert the dynamic property value to a regular expression.
- Convert the object itself to a dynamic test object.

You can find detail information on converting the property value to a regular expression in the below link.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.rational.test.ft.help%2FReplExactMatchPropwithPattern.htm

Also there is a nice blog on object map of RFT:
http://rftobjectmap.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find objects with changing properties you can consider to use the `TestObject.find` method. This allows you to access test objects without even having them in the object map. A good introduction to the find method is provided by IBM developerWorks: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0711_nowacki_nodwell/.